# Angular 13 Parent-Child not Communicating

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Trying to get an array from a parent component to a child component. The Angular docs make it look really simple but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The variable is activePost. Angular version is 13

Parent ts file (HomepageComponent):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from 'src/app/services/post.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Post } from 'src/app/models/post.model';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PostDisplayComponent } from '../components/post-display/post-display.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.scss']
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {
  posts?: Post[];
  category?:'';
  currentpost?: Post;
  currentIndex = -1;
  title = '';
  content='';

  
  activePost: Post;




  images: string[] =["../assets/img/damwon.jpg",
  "../assets/img/FPX.jpg",
  "../assets/img/2015skt.webp",
  "../assets/img/2017SSG.webp",
  "../assets/img/2014SSW.webp",
  "../assets/img/TPA.webp",
  "../assets/img/Fnatic.webp"]

  backgroundImage: string = '';
  constructor(private PostService: PostService,
              private route: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
    console.log(ran, Math.random()*100)
    this.backgroundImage = this.images[ran];

    this.retrieveposts();

  }
  refreshList(): void {
    this.currentpost = undefined;
    this.currentIndex = -1;
    this.retrieveposts();
  }

  retrieveposts(): void {
    this.PostService.getAll().snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c =>
          ({ id: c.payload.doc.id, ...c.payload.doc.data() })
        )
      )
    ).subscribe(data => {
      this.posts = data;
    });
  }

  setActivepost(post: Post, index: number): void {
    this.currentpost = post;
    this.currentIndex = index;
    console.log("Post:", post, "Index:", index);
    this.activePost = this.currentpost
    this.route.navigate(['/Read/'])
    
  }

}
```

Child ts file (post-display component)

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from 'src/app/models/post.model';
import { PostService } from 'src/app/services/post.service';
import { HomepageComponent } from 'src/app/homepage/homepage.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-display',
  templateUrl: './post-display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-display.component.scss']
})
export class PostDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() activePost: Post;

  @Output() refreshList: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  currentPost: Post = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    category:'',
    published: false,
    content: ''
  };
  message = '';

  constructor(private PostService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.activePost)
  }
 

}
```

Child HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 200px;">
  <div class="post">
    ACTIVE POST HERE:
    {{activePost}}
  </div>
```

Looking at the console, the child component always returns undefined for activePost. I'm not sure if this is because I dont have anything in the parent html code for the child to look at? I feel like I should just be able to do this in the .ts file.

Help would be appreciated. Let me know if there are other project docs I should share as well.

Edit, added parent html:

```
<header class="header" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + backgroundImage + ')'}">
    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="heading">
            <span class="small">Samsite:</span>
            Stat
            <span class="no-fill">check</span>
        </h1>
        <!--<a href="/editor" class="btn">write a blog</a>-->
    </div>
</header>



<section class="blogs-section">
  <div class="blog-card"
  *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index"
  >

    <h1>Title: {{ post.title }}</h1>
    <h2> Category: {{ post.category }}</h2>
    <p class="blog-overview"> Preview: {{ post.description }}</p>
    <div class="btn" (click)="setActivepost(post, i)">Read!</div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: we also need your parent HTML to answer you I guess

Comment: in your parent, the ActivePost looks empty

Comment: I will add the parent html. I was thinking this could be done in the ts alone though. activePost gets assigned a value in the function "setactivepost".

Comment: Does not look like parent/child relationship to me. That one is defined by the fact that one component renders another component (e.g. the selector of the child component can be found in the HTML template of the parent component). In your case, you'd be better off if you pass the id of the selected post to the route when you navigate to the details component and fetch the post by id.

Comment: This is not a parent child construct. Please reference https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: So if the parent-child relationship is only for communicating between components based on the DOM content, what's the accepted way to pass variables between components? If I could set up the url to include the post ID then I would, but I don't know how to dynamically generate urls in angular or how to make that routing work. I'd rather just pass the data to the other component and then have it render that data on a new page.